# How to delete multiple columns using multiple patterns?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file like this (delimited by \t):

```
gene1 previous name1
gene2 previous name2
gene3 previous name3
gene4 previous name4
```

I want to delete the columns that contain *gene2* and *gene4* in the first column. I know that I can search multiple patterns using *sed* or *awk* and a *|* but in reality my file have thousand of lines and I want to delete hundred of columns (I have a variable with the patterns I want to search for). How can I do this without having to write manually all the patterns?

Pattern variable:

```
gene2
gene4
```

Expected output:

```
gene1 previous name1
gene3 previous name3
```

I only want to grep the first column because the word *gene2* (or *gene4) could be in the third column.

Comment: `I have a variable with the patterns`: Show content of your variable with your attempted code

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do all of the patterns exist in a file? Should the script search for them all in the first column only? This should be trivial even with a largn number of input patterns.

Comment: You can use `sed` to take the contents of the 'pattern variable' to format into a single fixed string for `sed`, `grep` or `awk` to handle. Too bad you don't give any information to allow that answer to be written. Or just read the key word list with `grep`

Comment: update the question to show the expected output after applying the patterns (`gene2` / `gene4`) to the sample input

Comment: You're right! Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep`:

```
cat > in_file <<EOF
gene1 previous name1
gene2 previous name2
gene3 previous name3
gene4 previous name4
EOF

cat > pat_file <<EOF
gene2
gene4
EOF

grep -v -f pat_file in_file
```

Output:

```
gene1 previous name1
gene3 previous name3
```

Here, [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-v` : Print lines that do **not** match.
`-f file` : Obtain patterns from *file*, one per line.

Comment: add `-w` to ensure `gene2` does not match against `gene21`?